# Disable Hyper-V

Tags: windows-10, hyper-v, bluestacks

I have installed Bluestacks and when I try to open it, it says

> Disable Hyper-V from the control panel

But there's noting called Hyper-V in "Windows features" to disable.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Untick Windows Hypervisor Platform, then click okay. If that doesn't work open an elevated command prompt by pressing <kbd>[image: Windows Key]</kbd> +  <kbd>X</kbd> and then clicking on "`Windows Powershell (Admin)`" or "`Command Prompt (Admin)`" as seen below.

[image: Image for reference].

Once you have opened an elevated command prompt type in the following then restart your PC:

- `dism.exe /Online /Disable-Feature:Microsoft-Hyper-V`